# same path of url but pointing to different directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im trying to redirect this,

**www.example.com/about** *expect to matched with* **docs/about.html**
**www.example.com/register** *expect to matched with* **mod/register.php**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.+$
RewriteRule ^([^\.][a-z]+)$ docs/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.][a-z]+)$ mod/$1.php [L]
```

The first rewrite rule works great,
but the second rewrite rule won't work, it keeps showing 404 error.

Comment: That's because the first rule regex matches also `www.example.com/register`. The pattern is the same for both incoming URLs, so you have to figure out how to identify them as the substitution URLs are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have the same file in both places (e.g. `/docs/foo.html` *and* `/mod/foo.php`, you can do a check against the destination first before you rewrite:

```
# check for docs/.html first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/docs/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /docs/%1.html [L]

# If not .html, then check for mod/.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mod/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /mod/%1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate for your very good answer!! I have learned new things :D